# missing header in OBIEE reports on IE

Tags: obiee

I am new to OBIEE.
One of my report is working fine in CHROME browser.But when I try to open it in IE, its not showing it properly. The main header part of the report in missing.

Can anybody please help me with this.
I am using IE 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your IE browser cache. IE loves to mess up and corrupt it's locally stored files. Ctrl+Shift+Delete -> kill everythign and do NOT "Preserve Favorites website data"